Man gives girl metal sword then fights with wooden sword
I don't remember much other than there was a scene where a little girl had to run away, so one of her protectors started fighting some knights with a wooden sword, since he gave the girl his metal sword. He then got killed. When the girl was running away she accidentally stabbed her friend with the sword. That is all I remember, and it would help if you answered, since I've been looking for this movie or tv show for 5 years. Thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

Is this it?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcjQ4rQQ8H8

@WillFeldman probably has it! You should make your comment an answer so it can be upvoted accordingly.

Should the game-of-thrones tag be added to the question? Kind of feels wrong.

@JoelRondeau - we don't tag ID questions with their (potential) answer.

This is so close to the scene from Game of Thrones.  Are you sure about the 5 years - its only been 3+ years since this scene was shown.

That sounds like Game of Thrones season 1 episode 8, The Pointy End, (2011).

More Lannister guardsmen, this time led by Ser Meryn Trant of the
  Kingsguard, interrupt a "dancing" lesson between Syrio Forel and Arya.
  Syrio holds Arya back, questioning why Lord Eddard would send
  Lannister men to find Arya. She then refuses to go with them, and when
  they try to force the issue Syrio disarms and disables all of the
  lightly-armored guardsmen with his wooden practice sword. He tells
  Arya to run as he faces down Trant, noting that for himself, "The
  First Sword of Braavos does not run." Syrio's fate after this is
  unclear. 
Arya runs to the stables where the men waiting with their
  baggage were supposed to be to take them to the ship for Winterfell.
  The men are dead, but she finds her real sword, Needle, in the bottom
  of her trunk. Arya then starts to leave the stables. (Arya knows how
  to get out of the Red Keep via the tunnel under the castle that she
  found when she was chasing cats and followed the two conspirators).
  When a stableboy tries to grab her, Arya turns around brandishing
  Needle and accidentally runs him through and kills him. Horrified, she
  flees.

The fight between Syrio Forel (Arya's sword instructor) and the Lannister guardsmen is here.

I would say this is the right answer, except for the 5 year part of the question.  Its so close to this scene, I wonder whether the OP is correct about the amount of time that's passed.

Since they release only 12 or so episodes a season, it probably seems like it's been 5 years...
